# How to view bytea column data in a SELECT statement?

Tags: postgresql

I need to know how to visualize binary content in a postgresql table, whose column is of type `bytea`.

I found a possible solution to that problem, and it works well.

```
SELECT text(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

Do you know any other manner to accomplish this goal?

Comment: what's the problem with this?

Comment: There is not a problem. I was a little worried about the performance for large columns. But if this is the way to achieve it, for me it is ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All rigth my friend, go ahead that is the solution.
The function `text` is used to decode bytea into string.